# When invalidRequest exception occurs?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Exception occured - Reason:Code: invalidRequest
Message: Invalid request
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2022-07-12T15:38:50
request-id: c958304a-73df-4f8a-ac9e-f841956
a2bf8
client-request-id: c958304a-73df-4f8a-ac9e-f841956a2bf8
ClientRequestId: c958304a-73df-4f8a-ac9e-f841956a2bf8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you please describe a bit more which `API` you are trying to call and what exactly you are trying to implement? Its not clear which `graph API` endpoint you are calling.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron While creating "Item" Graph query throws an error when PersonOrGroup entry I add in a item AdditionalData's Dictionary object 



tempDict.Add(field.Key, field.Value); //tempDict.Add(Speakers, [{"LookupId":6,"LookupValue":"Sonam Gaikwad","Email":"sonam.gaikwad@NetVaultPlugIn2.onmicrosoft.com"}])

If i dont add this entry in dictionary everything works fine

Comment: I am trying to create List item(sharepoint online list item)

Comment: Would you kindly have a look at this [`official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and make sure you are passing the parameter correctly. I think the request format is incorrect. In addition please include the `full code snippet` how are you passing the `site-id` and `list-id`. Did you set the `Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All` permission?